# ERROR: jetified-image-4.8.4\res\layout\com_adobe_image_alert_dialog_buttonbar_material.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, resources, build.gradle

Complete error is

> ERROR: C:\Users\Dell.gradle\caches\transforms-3\ef32469b5667299698f5486ff3ea2243\transformed\jetified-image-4.8.4\res\layout\com_adobe_image_alert_dialog_buttonbar_material.xml:18: AAPT: error: resource bool/abc_allow_stacked_button_bar (aka com.creative.photo.editor:bool/abc_allow_stacked_button_bar) not found.

My complete app level build.gradle file is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
/* 1) Apply the Gradle Retrolambda Plugin */
//apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdk 34
//    buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.creative.photo.editor"
        namespace "com.creative.photo.editor"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
        manifestPlaceholders = [appPackageName: "${applicationId}"]
        renderscriptTargetApi 34
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    /* 2) Compile for Java 1.8 or greater */
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    /* 3) Exclude duplicate licenses */
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        pickFirst 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    repositories {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            gradlePluginPortal()
//            jcenter()
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
            maven {
                url "https://camerakit.bintray.com/other"
            }
        }
    }

    configurations {
        cleanedAnnotations
        implementation.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations:23.0.0'
        implementation.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations-java5:15.0'
        implementation.exclude group: 'com.intellij', module:'annotations'

    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        /* 4) Add the CSDK framework dependencies (Make sure these version numbers are correct) */
        implementation 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.2006-5'
        /* Add the CSDK framework dependencies (Make sure these version numbers are correct) */
        implementation 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.8.4'
        implementation 'com.localytics.android:library:4.0.1'
        implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
        implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
//        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.6.0'
        implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
//        implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.5.4"
        implementation 'com.startapp:inapp-sdk:4.11.0'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.4.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
        implementation files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.5.jar')
//        implementation 'io.alterac.blurkit:blurkit:1.1.1'
        implementation 'com.github.wonderkiln:blurkit-android:1.1.1'
//        implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'

    }
}
```